# Correct useage of dynamic variable variables within curly brackets?

Tags: php, variables, dynamic

Is the following use of the curly brackets `{ }` in `${str_replace(' ', '_', $group_name)}` valid, to invoke variable variables?

The `$group_name` itself should be provided by the `foreach loop`, but because many group names feature a space (e.g. `LICENSE INFORMATION` is two words with a space in between and is probably an illegal variable name) - therefore I've had to include a `str_replace` to replace the space with an underscore.  All of this ultimately takes place inside the curly brackets `{ ... }` which I'm hoping will cause PHP to parse it properly.

```
<?php   
...

foreach ($grouped as $IMSKU){

        $all_grouped_blocks = [];

        foreach ($IMSKU['Group_Name'] as $group_name_index => $group_name){


            if (!isset(${str_replace(' ', '_', $group_name)})){ 

            ${str_replace(' ', '_', $group_name)} = []; 

            ${str_replace(' ', '_', $group_name)} = '<th colspan="3">'."$group_name".'</th>';


            array_push($all_grouped_blocks,${str_replace(' ', '_', $group_name)});
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: So, did it work?  Personally, since you use that convention several times, I would do something like `$key =  str_replace( ... )` and then refer to `$$key`

Comment: @TimMorton Since I have to immediately run an `!isset` test, I'm worried that setting the variable beforehand in any way could confuse the test?

Comment: This is where unit testing (and TDD) would be very helpful, but I digress. Off the top of my head, it seems to me that `$key` would always be set; you would still need to check `isset($$key)` though.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can prove it's working by analogous example - say if you agree:

```
<?php

$big_boy = "Ain't this fella big.<br />";
$small_toy = "Size doesn't matter.<br />";
$double_trouble = "Team Rocket is blasting awaaaaaay!<br />";

$theme = array(0 => 'big boy', 1 =>'small toy', 2 => 'double trouble');

foreach ($theme as $key => $value){

echo ${str_replace(' ','_',$value)};


}
?>
```

Output:

```
Ain't this fella big. 
Size doesn't matter. 
Team Rocket is blasting awaaaaaay!
```